# Display Custom Taxonomy Terns ordered by meta_value

Tags: custom-taxonomy, order, terms

I got stuck with ordering custom taxonomy. I've created a hierarchical custom taxonomy called **Brand** and created some meta tags including one called **position**. Now I would like to display my terms ordered by **position** meta tag. I tried doing this:

```
<?php
$taxonomy = 'brand';
    $term_args=array(
        'hide_empty' => false,
        'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
        'meta_key' => 'position',
        'parent' => 0,
    );
?>

<?php $tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy, $
<?php foreach ( $tax_terms as $tax_term ) : ?>
    <h2><?php echo $tax_term->name; ?></h2>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

But as I can see `get_terms()` doesn't support `'orderby' = 'meta_value_num'` and terms are ordered by name. Is there any way to display them ordered by position?

Thanks for your help!
Patryk

Comment: And the position field is just a number correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the position field is filled with numbers to give order: have a look at [`ksort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php).

```
<?php 

            $terms = get_terms('brands');

            // Let's create our own array and then reorder it
            $order_terms = array();
            foreach( $terms as $term ) {
                $position = set_up_the_position_meta_here;
                $order_terms[$position] ='<h2>'.$term->name.'</h2>';
            }

            // now lets reorder the array based on keys (position)
            ksort($order_terms);

            // time to display
            foreach( $order_terms as $order_term ) {
                echo $order_term;
            }

        ?>
```